# How long does the Android Developer Console take to update sales information?

Tags: android, google-play

How frequently does the android dev. console update things like total downloads and revenue? More importantly, does anyone know at what time it updates at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Google,

> These statistics are refreshed on a daily basis at 12:00 am PST.

You can see the original support document [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?hl=en).